# Is it possible to create an app that auto responds to phone calls with a text message, and auto replies to received texts and emails?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have not been able to find any information about the topic online, so I am assuming it is not possible, but is there a way to create an app that when turned on will respond to all incoming calls by sending them to voicemail and responding with a text message? I know you can set the reply with message in iOS6, but we would want the message to be sent automatically when the call is recieved, currently the respond with message the user still needs to hit a button when the call comes in to send this. We would also want to respond to any incoming SMS/imessages with a text. As well as reply automatically via email to any incoming emails. If anyone could link me to an apple site or somewhere that says you can't do this? Thanks for your help.

Edit - is there any way to get information about notifications for these items? I was thinking if you can't directly handle the call itself, on a timed loop you could check to see if there were any missed calls or any info relating to those? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not unless you want to develop and application for jailbroken phones, which will not be allowed in the Apple App Store.

Comment: any link to something from apple saying this? I believe it, just need to prove it.

Comment: @njj56 There is no API for this so there is nothing to link to. You can't prove a negative. :)

Comment: Sorry I dont. I am not sure that it is explicitly forbidden, however Apple provide no public API for it, so any use of a private API would make an app ineligable for App Store approval.

Comment: However it is possible, as a number of 3rd party jailbreak developers have produced working solutions. One is iBlackList http://www.iblacklist.com.br/